# Access the array value

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
    ['data'] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
            [3] => d
        )

    ['id'] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 7
            [3] => 8
        )

)
```

This data ($form_data) coming from form. How to accessing this array? I cannot access with following:

```
$data= $form_data['data'][0]; or
$id = $form_data['id'][0];
```

I just accessing with array_values() function and following:

```
$data= $form_data[0][0]; or
$id = $form_data[0][0];
```

But i dont want use array_values() function. Why I cant access my array natural way?

Comment: Perhaps because you already have those quotes as part of your key, if that's the output from print_r().... `$data= $form_data["'data'"][0];`.... or better yet, fix the keys wherever you're generating this array

Comment: What error are you getting with `$data= $form_data['data'][0];`? That should work on that array.

Comment: @MarkBaker they were output by print_r(). data coming from array in the form. etc: <input name="data['data'][]" value="a"> and more input.

Comment: @MinistryofChaps they arent any error. I can use with array_values(). but i want use with assoc.

Comment: If the array you're accessing is actually the array you have provided, it should work. See [this example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/72894ef28bfe25599e45a1cca8074a3db2f190ae).

Comment: @MarkBaker you're right. Problem is quotes. my input name is name="data['data'][]". I did remove quotes. like: name="data[data][]". Thanks your help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine man, make sure you are building your array correctly. This code works flawlessly. There's not much information on how you built the array, so I hope this model helps you.

```
<?php
$array = array(
    'data' => array
        (
            0 => 'a',
            1 => 'b',
            2 => 'c',
            3 => 'd'
        ),

    'id' => array
        (
            0 => 5,
            1 => 6,
            2 => 7,
            3 => 8
        )
);
```

Now you can call back on your array using your preferred method:

```
$a = $array['data'][0];
$b = $array['data'][1];
$c = $array['data'][2];

echo $a . $b . $c;
// outputs 'abc'
```

Also call the `id`:

```
$fiv = $array['id'][0];
$six = $array['id'][1];
$sev = $array['id'][2];

echo $fiv . $six . $sev;
// outputs '567'
```